# How to get the rank of a score you just posted to GameCenter?

Tags: game-center, rank

is there a way to get the player's score rank he's just posted even if the score is not his best?

[GKScore reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:] is used to post score to GameCenter, but its 'rank' is always zero. the 'rank' value only valid when calling [GKLeaderboard loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:], but its the rank of player's best score today/week/alltime.

the best place would be [GKScore reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:], make the 'rank' value valid when it returns from gamecenter.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

AFIK there's no such solutions.
GameCenter stores player's best score only.

[Read this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH6-SW13)

So, if you really want to do that, you have to rank the player by your self.

1. Retrieve all scores from the leader board.
2. Check the rank of the current score.

-Sample codes below

```
-(void) findRankWithScore: (int64_t)score
{
    GKLeaderboard *leaderboard = [[GKLeaderboard alloc] init];

    if (leaderboard != nil) {
        leaderboard.category = @"YourCategory";
        leaderboard.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeWeek; //or all time, day... pick one.

        [leaderboard loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error) {
            int rank = 0;
            if (error == nil && scores != nil) {
                for (GKScore* refScore in scores) {
                    //NOTE: Retrieved score array is sorted already.
                    if (refScore.value <= score) {
                        rank = refScore.rank - 1;
                        if (rank < 1) {
                            rank = 1;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
                //show the rank to player. using delegate, notification, popups etc...

            }else {
                //handle errors
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

In addition, it cost a lot to retrieving all the scores from GameCenter for each rank findings.

So, I recommend you to store the score array and reuse it, even though it make a bit of sacrifice of your ranking accuracy.
(And refresh the score array in some time interval or something like that)